# Resizing a Rotated Div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery `resizeable()` on a div which is rotated 270deg. I want the div to be resizable from top and bottom when rotated (meaning horizontal rotation on 0 deg rotation).

The problem is if I use resizable on that div it starts changing its position as well. I have created a fiddle to showcase the problem:

```
 $(function () {
    $(".cediv").resizable({
      handles: 'e, w'
    });
  });
```

[Jsfiddle jQuery resize on rotated Div](https://jsfiddle.net/m5rbaenx/26/)

I just want the div to be resizable from top and bottom when its rotated. I am trying to fir the idea into a editable Y axis for a chart if that helps.
Has anyone encountered this problem?, if yes could you please help in the way forward.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable with jQuery UI

```
$(".cediv").resizable({
      handles: 'e, w'
    }).rotatable({

});
```